# Asking someone "For how much did you buy it"?

Tags: prepositions, questions, past-simple

Would it be right to say

> For how much did you buy it?

Is there  any other way to ask? I think this question sounds awkward.

Could you please explain why I feel the question is awkward?

Comment: "How much did you pay for it?"or "How much did you buy it for?"

Comment: It's correct but very formal. I'd go with @CinCout.

Comment: It's worse than formal. It's a hyper-correction. There is no rule that forbids ending a sentence with a preposition. That "style" was fobbed off on people hundreds of years ago by other people who wanted English to be more like Latin.

Answer (score 4):

The way you have asked is correct, but quite formal.

As suggested in the comments, I would recommend either of the following:

> "How much did you pay for it?"
>
> "How much did you buy it for?"

Answer (score 2):

For how much did you buy it?

The sentence is grammatical, but the folliwing are more appropriate and common:

> How much did it cost you?
>
> How much did you pay for it?

You can also say:

> What did you pay for it?